# How to measure Polyline with fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I would like to measure a polyline with fabric js (or regular js). So far I can draw the polyline but it only measures the distance from the mousedown to the mouseup rather than measuring the entire line distance. For example if I was to draw a circle it would return '0' for the distance because the start and end vertices are the same, whereas I would like to have measured the circle circumference. Here is the code:

```
                    var Calculate = {
                        lineLength: function (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
                            return normalizedSize * (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 * 1 - x1 * 1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 * 1 - y1 * 1, 2)));
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabric.Polyline.points contains all the points that are defining your polyline.

Instead of measuring with the mouse cursor, add the new point to the polyline and then do the calculation based on poins:

```
var Calculate = {
    lineLength: function (line) {
        var distance = 0;
        for (var i=0; i < line.points.length - 1; i++) {
            var p1 = line.points[i];
            var p2 = line.points[i + 1];
            distance += normalizedSize * (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p2.x - p1.x, 2) + Math.pow(p2.y - p1.y, 2)));
        }
        return distance;
    }
}
```

This should calculate the line distance correctly.

Comment: very nice solution, but its not returning a value for some reason. must have a bug I can't see

Comment: I do not know, you should setup your code in a working fiddle, removing the unnecesary color and other things, and focus on length measure

Comment: no use -1 because you will always comput distance to next pont. at 1 point you do not measure, at 2 points you measure 1 to 2 [ point 0 and point 1in array ], and exit iteration before point 2.